# Haskell ,implement any function with foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I am trying to imlpment a function, that gives `True`, when at least one element in the list fulfilled the condition `(>5)`

```
*Main> any (>5) [1..]
True
```

This is my code which is working:

```hs
any1 f [] = True
any1 f (x:xs) = f x || any f xs
```

but I want to implement it with `foldr`, how can I do it?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What have you tried, what is not working with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `foldr` pattern on a list basically replaces:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, …, xn]
```

with:

```
f x1 (f x2 (… (f xn z) …))
```

It thus replaces the "cons" constructor `(:)` with `f`, and the empty list `[]` with `z`.

You thus should look how `any1 f` has a value on which it maps for the empty list, and define a function `g` that takes as first parameter an element `xi` and a second element the result of `foldr g [xi+1, xi+2, …, xn]`:

```
any1 :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
any1 f = foldr g …
    where g … = …
```

where you need to fill in `…`.

Comment: any1 function only takes one parameter,is that means f is a function that takes 1 parameter,which f is a function,(>5) and its parameter is a list?

Comment: @JohnTang: no `any1` does not take one parameter. Note that `foldr g ...` (if `...` is one expression) produces a function. A function that will take a foldable and maps it to a `Bool`. In functional programming "functions" are first-class citizens, so these are passed as parameters, and as a result. Due to *currying*, the function `any (>5)`  thus produces a new function that checks if any element of the foldable is greater than `5`.